# gps Location and local time

Tags: java, android, time, gps

I try to get the local time from Location.getTime() with the following formula:

```
long localTime = location.getTime() + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
```

;

but I get different times on different Android versions and on different emulators. How can I always get the correct time?

The full code is:

```
private final long TimeOffset = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationlistener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            boolean wasNull = locFine == null;
            if (location.getProvider().equals(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                locFine = location;
                //long TimeOffset = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getRawOffset();
                long gpsTime = locFine.getTime() + TimeOffset;
                long SystemTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                timeOffsetGPS = gpsTime - SystemTime;
                Date dtgps = new Date(locFine.getTime());
                Log.d("Location", "Time GPS: " + dtgps); // This is what we want!
                if (context != null && a != null) {
                    if (wasNull) lib.ShowToast(a, getString(R.string.gotGPS));
                    /*
                    lib.ShowMessage(a,"gps time: " + dtgps
                            + "\nsystem time: " + new Date(SystemTime)
                            + "\noffset: " + timeOffsetGPS / 1000
                            + "\ncorrected gpstime: " + new Date(gpsTime));
                    */
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            if (a != null) lib.ShowToast(context,  context.getString(R.string.gpsstatus) + " " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            if (context != null) lib.ShowToast(context, s + " " + getString(R.string.enabled));
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            if (context != null)
                lib.ShowMessage(context, s + " " + getString(R.string.disabled));
        }
    };
    try {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, locationlistener);}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the getTime() method of the Location class, at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html:

> Return the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

So, inside your onLocationChanged() method, you can get a Date object like this that represents the timestamp when the location fix was obtained (you do have this at one point in the middle of your code):

```
Date fixDateTime = new Date(location.getTime());
```

Since the Date object stores the date/time internally as UTC, you can use any of the date/time formatting functions to display that timestamp in any time zone that is relevant.  You don't need to add or subtract any offsets.

If you are not familiar with the date/time formatting functions, start with reading through the documentation for SimpleDateFormat at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: I know that location.getTime() normally gets UTC-Time, but I don't need a formatted date but the local time in milliseconds. Of course I could parse the formatted date again to get the local time, but that wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: What do you want to do with the local time?  That information may help to give a better answer.

Comment: I want to calculate an offset between local time from gps and system time to correct the system time (if needed).

Comment: You can get that offset in milliseconds by using TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset(), then add that offset to the result of location.getTime().

Comment: I used RawOffset before and I got the correct time on my Android tablet, but not on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and S7.......

Comment: I am not aware of any other method to determine the offset between the UTC time zone and the time zone set on the device.  But, to try to help, maybe there is a different approach that would solve your problem; but I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do.  You say that you want to "correct the system time (if needed)".  What are you going to do with that corrected system time?  What is the high-level purpose of this piece of code?

Comment: I save the latitude and the longitute and other data  together with a timestamp in a database. The timestamp must be local time not utc.

Comment: Would it be possible to store the timestamp in UTC along with the device's time zone, so that the local time could be reconstructed later?  Most clients (including Android) have ways to take a UTC timestamp and give you the local time for a specific time zone.

Comment: But the time I get from Location is not UTC! It is UTC +1 and UTC +2 (on different Devices)